# Where do I put my .a files

Tags: filesystem, c++, make, libraries, makefile

I installed Irrlicht earlier and realized the package didn't come with the libIrrlicht.a that it's supposed to. After an hour of trying to understand why it wasn't working and compiling the necessary files, I finally have what I need. Now my libIrrlicht.a is in /usr/include/irrlicht and I'm wondering where it should be so I only have to write -lIrrlicht in my Makefile like I used to be able to a year ago and I currently do with every other library I use instead of the whole path?

Comment: How did you obtain `libirrlicht.a`? If you'd installed the `libirrlicht-dev` package (found in the `universe` repository) then the library would have been installed in the correct system library location and the linker would find it via the default library search paths

Comment: I installed libirrlicht-dev trought apt. Right now after running the dpkg -L libirrlicht-dev it says the libirrlicht.a is there /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIrrlicht.a but I still can't just use -lIrrlicht in my makefile and have it work properly.

Comment: In that case I suggest you [edit] your question to include the contents of your Makefile, the command you're using to build, and the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

Install the `libirrlicht-dev`.

To see the list of files installed by the package:

```
dpkg -L libirrlicht-dev
```

Also, on the Ubuntu site:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libdevel/libirrlicht-dev

Comment: I ran the command and it says I have it here: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIrrlicht.a